# Django Queryset Postgres

Tags: django, postgresql, django-queryset

I am writing queryset that will return this type

| date | total_shipping_fee |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-04-16 | 5,000 |
| 2021-04-17 | 100,000 |

where

```
class Payments(models.Model):
    created = models.DateTimeField()
    .....
```

```
SELECT DATE(created) from payment_payment .... group by 'created' -> outputs a correct query
```

My question is how to query/ or cast

```
Payment.objects.filter(created_range=("2021-05-14", "2021-05-14")).values('created').annotate(total_shipping_fee=Sum('total_shipping_fee'))
```

so that I can have queryset in above raw sql. I think that is my problem to CAST DATE(created) in django queryset. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can work with:

```
from django.db.models import F, Sum

Payment.objects.filter(
    created__date_range=('2021-05-14', '2021-05-14')
).values(create_date=F('created__date')).annotate(
    total_shipping_fee=Sum('total_shipping_fee')
).order_by('create_date')
```

here we thus first takes as values the truncated date of the `DateTimeField`, and then we use [**`.order_by(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#order-by) to enforce grouping by that date.

The output is a `QuerySet` of dictionaries, each with two items: `{ 'create_date': …, 'total_shipping_fee': … }`.